# How can we visulaize a knowledge graph created using spacy(Python) in protege?

Tags: python, networkx, spacy, protege, knowledge-graph

I have created a knowledge graph from below dataframe using spacy and networkx library in Python.
Now I want to visualize this Graph in Protege. Is this possible? If yes then how this can be done?
I am attaching the dataframe and code for creating the Graph below.

```
kg_df = pd.DataFrame({'source':source, 'target':target, 'edge':relations})


    G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(kg_df, "source", "target", 
                            edge_attr=True, create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())

    plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k = 0.5) # k regulates the distance between nodes
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', node_size=1500, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues, pos = pos)
    plt.show()
    print(kg_df)
```

[image: kg_df]